# UnicodeDecodeError on byte type

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, decode, utf-16

Using Python 3.4 I'm getting the following error when trying to decode a byte type using utf-32

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:.\SharqBot.py", line 1130, in <module>
    fullR=s.recv(1024).decode('utf-32').split('\r\n')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-32-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-3: codepoint not in range(0x110000)
```

and the following when trying to decode it into utf-16

```
  File "c:.\SharqBot.py", line 1128, in <module>
    fullR=s.recv(1024).decode('utf-16').split('\r\n')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x0a in position 374: truncated data
```

When I decode using utf-8 there is no error. s is a socket connected to the twitch IRC server irc.chat.twitch.tv on port 80.

It receives the following:

```
b':tmi.twitch.tv 001 absolutelyabot :Welcome, GLHF!\r\n:tmi.twitch.tv 002 absolutelyabot :Your host is tmi.twitch.tv\r\n:tmi.twitch.tv 003 absolutelyabot :This server is rather new\r\n:tmi.twitch.tv 004 absolutelyabot :-\r\n:tmi.twitch.tv 375 absolutelyabot :-\r\n:tmi.twitch.tv 372 absolutelyabot :You are in a maze of twisty passages, all alike.\r\n:tmi.twitch.tv 376 absolutelyabot :>\r\n'
```

Am I doing something wrong when trying to decode to utf 16 and 32? The reason I want to use utf-32 is because occasionally someone sends a character that is not in utf-8 and I want to be able to recieve that instead of it throwing an error because utf-8 does not support that character.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: use `decode('utf-8', errors='replace')` for example.

Comment: I'm not trying to avoid the error all together, I'm trying to recieve the characters that aren't supported in utf-8.

Comment: So you can try to decode the whole line using UTF-8. If an exception is thrown, *only then try an alternative charset*. I doubt IRC protocl would allow UTF-16, 32 *ever*, because of embedded NULs

Comment: "When I decode using utf-8 there is no error".  So why do you think UTF-16 or UTF-32 should work??

Answer (score 21):

try using encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'

Comment: @CodeWarrior: Presumably the original text is `latin-1` (the friendly name for ISO-8859-1) encoded, not `utf-8`. Or it isn't, but `latin-1` is a one-to-one encoding where every byte maps to a character, so it's just masking errors and producing gibberish. Either way.

Answer (score 3):

*Every* Unicode ordinal can be represented in UTF-8, if `decode`ing as UTF-8 isn't working, that's because the bytes being transmitted are in a different encoding, or the data is mixed text and binary data, and only some of it is UTF-8. Odds are the text *is* UTF-8 encoded (most network protocols are), so non-UTF-8 data would be framing data or the like, and would need to be parsed to extract the text data.

Any attempt to mask such an error in the text/binary case would just be silencing problems, not fixing them. You need to know the encoding of the data (and the format, if it's not all text data with a single encoding), and use that. The data you receive doesn't magically become UTF-16 or UTF-32 because you want it to.

Comment: IRC does not specify text encoding.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with decode/encode('utf-16-le'). I tried it and it was OK to me. But I am not realy clear why. :P

Comment: Please try to be more clear with your answer and explain why this worked for you. Perhaps describe what is different between your approach and the OP