# Problems handling file with Chinese characters

Tags: python, utf-16, chinese-locale

I have a file (with a custom extension) that's dumped by a tool. The file is a mix of English and Chinese & Korean characters. The file can be read with notepad and the non-English characters are visible. By running the following code I was able to determine that the file is in UTF16-LE encoding:

```
def check_encoding(filename):
        """
        """
        fh = open(filename, 'rb') # open the file in raw binary mode
        data = fh.read() # read the contents of the file
        return chardet.detect(data)['encoding']
```

This returns 'UTF-16LE'.

I have a method that process this file where I do this:

```
file = open(filename, 'r', encoding='UTF-16-LE')
for line in file:
```

However when I execute this method I get this error (at the start of the for loop):

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position
>   106-107: illegal encoding

I've tried opening the file with encoding = UTF8 but that throws the same error (albeit for the utf-8 codec at a different position)

The file is too big for me to manually narrow down to the exact line that's causing problems.

Now here's the interesting part. I make a copy of the file (lets call it copy.xyz). Now I open the original file in Notepad++ and copy all the content, paste it into copy.xyz (also opened in Notepad++) and save it (ctrl+s). Now if I try to run my method on the copy it doesn't throw any error!!! Can anyone help me figure out what's going on here and how I can fix the errors on the original file?

EDIT: I opened the file in raw binary mode and tried to figure out the encoding for the characters on each line using chardet. That gave me  12 different encodings. What would be the next step?

Comment: What Python version are you using? Have you tried opening this file as raw binary and decoding? Is it possible to provide a few lines that are causing the problem?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6. I need to read the file line by line and then extract some data from each line based on certain conditions being met. Is that possible if I read the file as raw binary? Unfortunately I cannot share the contents of the file.

Comment: If you open file as raw binary, you need to encode it to `utf-16-le` before performing any operation on it, but doing it this way will give you more control on what exactly throws an error. There's always a possibility, that file was wrongly encoded in the first place, and your Notepad++ saves it to the right format. Or your data was glued together from multiple files, and between string-encoded 'utf-16-le', there are some binary headers which can't be encoded(you can skip them tho). Hard to tell without actual file.

Comment: The file is glued together from several sources so it might be a mix of encodings, like you say. I'll try reading each line in raw binary format and the use try:except blocks to decode it with different types of encoding formats. Thanks @Pythonist

Comment: *"The file is too big for me to manually narrow down to the exact line that's causing problems."* - It says the error is on  position 106-107. How can you not narrow that down?

Comment: @Pythonist based on this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36140147/unicodedecodeerror-on-byte-type I set the encoding to 'ISO-8859-1' and now I don't get any errors when trying to read the file in 'r' mode. But when trying to write each line to an output file (using the same encoding 'ISO-8859-1'), the characters are sandwiched with 'NUL'.