# Gensim saving word vectors in txt format error

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

My issue is the following. I have some pretrained vectors saved in txt format, I load them in a dict. But when I try to save them after training them again in gensim it gives me an error, like the following:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-32-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-3: code point not in range(0x110000)
```

I'm using this code to create the gensim word2vec:

```
w2vObject = gensim.models.Word2Vec(min_count=1, sample=threshold, sg=1,size=dimension, negative=15, iter=epochsNum, window=3) # create only the shell

print('Starting vocab build')
# t = time()
w2vObject.build_vocab(sentences, progress_per=10000) #here is the vocab being built as told in google groups gensim

print(w2vObject.wv['the'], 'before train')
```

Then I'm replacing the current untrained vectors with:

```
f = codecs.open(f'../../../WordNetGraphHD/StorageEmbeddings/EmbeddingFormat{dimension}.txt')##os.path.join(GLOVE_DIR, 'glove.6B.100d.txt'))
embeddings_index = {}
for num, line in enumerate(f):
    values = my_split(line) # line.split('\t')
    word = values[0].rstrip()
    # vector = ''.join(num for num in values[1:])
    vector = values[1]
    if len(vector) != 300:
        print(line, 'here not 300')

    else:
        coefs = np.asarray(vector)

f.close()
```

This code replaces the untrained random vectors wit my own pretrained:

```
i = 0
for elem in w2vObject.wv.vocab:
    if elem in embeddings_index.keys():
        w2vObject.wv[elem] = embeddings_index[elem]
        i += 1
        print('Found one', i)

print(i)
```

Next I train them again with gensim:

```
w2vObject.train(sentences, total_examples=w2vObject.corpus_count, epochs=epochsNum)#w2vObject.iter)
```

Finally save them:

```
print(w2vObject.wv, 'after train')
w2vObject.wv.save_word2vec_format('./GensimOneWNet.txt', binary=False)
print('saved')
```

If I don't replace the vectors with my own saving works, but I need to replace them and save them as txt, any help?

EDIT:

Here is my_split() function:

```
def my_split(s):
    return list(re.split("-?\d+.?\d*(?:[Ee]-\d+)?", s))[0] ,list(re.findall("-?\d+.?\d*(?:[Ee]-\d+)?", s))
```

And here is a bit of data 300 dimensions for the embedding_index:

```
'hood -0.013093032778433955 -0.004199660490964164 -0.013285915004532987 0.004154925177649314 -0.004331536946207293 -0.013220217973950956 -0.004774150107654365 0.004774714449991327 0.0040749706101727646...
's gravenhage 0.01400977963089465 -0.0047073654478706935 -0.004326147699308312 0.01323622314514233 -0.004702524319745591 0.004695915697719624 0.00497792763673179 -0.004391661500805715 0.0046651111592470...
'tween 0.008467020793348493 -0.008027116343722267 0.007882368315816719 0.00754852526967863 0.008563484027417608 0.00812782576892597 0.008192394872536986 0.0075759585496093206...
```

Added code here:
[Python code runs fine without my vectors, crashes with them](https://pastebin.com/GKPnENxv)

Populate embedding_index I go through all the words and vectors in the txt and if for some reason a vector is not 300 dim, skip it:

```
f = codecs.open(f'../../../WordNetGraphHD/StorageEmbeddings/EmbeddingFormat{dimension}.txt', encoding='utf-8')##os.path.join(GLOVE_DIR, 'glove.6B.100d.txt'))
embeddings_index = {}
for num, line in enumerate(f):
    values = my_split(line) # line.split('\t')
    word = values[0].rstrip()
    vector = values[1]
    if len(vector) != 300:
        print(line, 'here not 300')
    else:
        coefs = np.asarray(vector)
        embeddings_index[word] = coefs

f.close()
```

EDIT2:
Here is the stack trace of the full error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "GensimTestSave.py", line 136, in <module>
    w2vObject.wv.save_word2vec_format('./GensimOneWNet.txt', binary=False) #encoding='utf-8' )
  File "/home/pedalo/anaconda3/envs/ltu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 1453, in save_word2vec_format
    fname, self.vocab, self.vectors, fvocab=fvocab, binary=binary, total_vec=total_vec)
  File "/home/pedalo/anaconda3/envs/ltu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py", line 291, in _save_word2vec_format
    fout.write(utils.to_utf8("%s %s\n" % (word, ' '.join(repr(val) for val in row))))
  File "/home/pedalo/anaconda3/envs/ltu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py", line 291, in <genexpr>
    fout.write(utils.to_utf8("%s %s\n" % (word, ' '.join(repr(val) for val in row))))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-32-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-3: code point not in range(0x110000)
```

Comment: Try manually specifying a different encoding when you save. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36140147/unicodedecodeerror-on-byte-type).

Comment: Manually? Where? Could you show me an example? I'm looking at the answer but unsure where is needed

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem like you can based on the gensim docs. Can you check that your `embedding_index` is non-empty when you replace the untrained vectors?

Comment: Yes it is not empty, I can print the keys and vecs.

Comment: Your question is missing the step where you populate `embedding_index`. Can you edit it to include this?

Comment: (1) Show the full error you've received, including tracebacks, so it's clear which lines (of your code & any libraries) are involved; (2) what is `my_split()`?; (3) where is `embeddings_index` populated?; (4) can you combine all your code into a single block that, when run in its entirety, both succeeds in saving (after the `build_vocab()` then fails (after your vector-patching)? Ignore `train()` entirely unless it seems required to get the error.

Comment: Yes I will reformat the code, first I will wait until the error appears, is at the end of the process. Then I will paste my code into pastebin.

Comment: @duncster94 Added the code for populating embedding_index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it now. Apparently I was trying to use a nd.array() but of strings as coefficients and gensim uses an nd.array(floats) that was the problem where my own vectors when switching  to the .wv[] were of type [str]. So It ended up being empty.

The switching of vectors now is done like:

```
for elem in setIntersection:
    if len(embeddings_index[elem]) != 300:
        print('here', elem) #cast it to the fire
    w2vObject.wv[elem] = np.asarray(embeddings_index[elem], dtype=np.float32)
print('Done!!!')
```

Thanks for your comments they helped me figure it out.